# Asp.net mvc4 dropdown binding to checkboxes with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a project based on ASP.NET MVC4, SQL Server 2012, EF.

In my edit form I need bind dropdown to checkboxes which display on the page. And when checked one or many checkboxes in the dropdown need to loading values from database which according to special rows in table. Here is my code to demonstrate what i have in this moment:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult StudentEdit(int id)
{
   Student student = repo.GetStudentById(id);

   ViewBag.EducationProgramBachelorId = new SelectList(
   context.EducationProgramBachelors, "EducationProgramBachelorId", "ProgramName",     
   student.EducationProgramBachelorId);
   return View(student);
}

public JsonResult ProgramList(int Id)
{
   var model = context.EducationProgramBachelors;
   var program = from s in model
                 where s.UniversityId == Id
                 select s;

   return Json(new SelectList(program, "EducationProgramBachelorId", "ProgramName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**View**

```
@{     
  List<ViewModels.AssignedUniversities> universities = ViewBag.Universities;

  foreach (var university in universities)
  {
     <div>
         <input type="checkbox"
                class="checkboxUniversities"
                name="selectedLatUniversities"
                value="@university.UniversityNameShort"
                @(Html.Raw(university.IsSelected ? "checked=\"checked\"" : ""))/>
         @university.UniversityNameShort
     </div>
   }
}

@Html.DropDownList("EducationProgramBachelorId", String.Empty)
```

**JS Function**

```
$(function () {
    $(".checkboxUniversities").change(function () {
        $.getJSON('/ControllerName/ProgramList/' + 1, function (data) {
            var items = '<option>Select a Program</option>';
            $.each(data, function (i, program) {
                items += "<option value='" + program.Value + "'>" + program.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $('#EducationProgramBachelorId').html(items);
        });
    });
});
```

I'm stopped on this step in my JS function:

```
$.getJSON('/ControllerName/ProgramList/' + 1, function (data)
```

Because I don't know how i can get and send int[] array of my UniversityId and how transform it in the my Json View. Can anybody help me with this situation?

In this line get('/ControllerName/ProgramList/' + 1, 1 - it's a test value to check work or dont work my script.

Between Student and University is many-to-many relationships.

P.S.: Sorry for my English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to return an array of Ids whenever a checkbox is clicked, and then populate a dropdown with the data corresponding to the ids, correct?

I would recommend using the full extent of the MVC framework to do the heavy lifting for you, namely:

- Return a partial view instead of a (json) int array
- In the partial view, just create the dropdown menu using MVC:s normal Model-View tools
- Insert the menu into a placeholder `<div>` on your main view

It would look something like the following.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ProgramList(int id){
    var model = context.EducationProgramBachelors;
    var program = from s in model
               where s.UniversityId == Id
               select s;

    return PartialView("studentProgram", program);
}
```

**Partial view (named "studentProgram")**

```
@model IEnumerable<Student>

@Html.DropDownFor("EducationProgramBachelorId", new SelectList(Model, "EducationProgramBachelorId", "ProgramName"))
```

**Main view**

```
@{     
    List<ViewModels.AssignedUniversities> universities = ViewBag.Universities;

    foreach (var university in universities)
    {
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox"
                class="checkboxUniversities"
                name="selectedLatUniversities"
                value="@university.Id"
                @(Html.Raw(university.IsSelected ? "checked=\"checked\"" : ""))/>
                    @university.UniversityNameShort
        </div>
     }
}

 <div id="dropdown-placeholder"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $(".checkboxUniversities").change(function (event) {
        var id = $(event.target).val();
        $.get('/ControllerName/ProgramList/' + id, function (data) {
            $("#dropdown-placeholder").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

This should simplify things a lot. The Id for the university should be added to the checkboxes as their values, and later gotten via the `change` function's `target` property.

A few caveats, though.

1. I don't know the exact structure of your `Student` class, so you may have to tweak that if I have made some wrong assumptions.
2. I wrote this code directly into the StackOverflow window and have not tested it, so there may be typos

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's the same what I have at this moment. In this line get('/ControllerName/ProgramList/' + 1, 1 - it's a test value to check work or dont work my script, your answer is awesome, but i still dont know what I must send instead of 1

Comment: Ideally 1 - it's the selected UniversityId in my checkbox